# Prove that a random variable is nondegenerate

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I want to prove that $X$ is not constant w.p. 1. Is it enough to show that $E(X-E(X))\neq 0$?

Answer (score 2):

If you could show that, it would certainly be enough to claim that $X$ is nondegenerate -- because $\mathbb{E}[X-\mathbb{E}[X]]=0$ for every degenerate random variable $X$.

Unfortunately, though, there's no way that you can show that: it turns out that for *any* random variable $X$ which has a finite mean, it is always true by linearity of the expectation that
$$
\mathbb{E}[X-\mathbb{E}[X]]=\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X]]=\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[X]=0.
$$

If you look to variance instead, however, you can salvage your result: a degenerate random variable has $\text{Var}[X]=0$, where
$$
\text{Var}[X]=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X])^2.
$$
Proving that a variable has non-zero variance is certainly sufficient to show that it is nondegenerate.

Comment: Thanks, so it is enough to show $\mathrm{Var}(X)=0$. Is this usually the shortest way to prove it?

Comment: That depends a lot on the form in which $X$ is given. There are a lot of facts about degenerate variables you could use; if $X=c$ with probability $1$, then $X$ has: CDF $F(x)=1_{x\geq c}$; MGF $M(t)=e^{ct}$; characteristic function $\chi(t)=e^{ict}$; etc.